# Remove a checkbox that is being created dynamically in a loop

Tags: c#, dynamic, checkbox, listbox, checklistbox

I have a bunch of code that dynamicly creates some controls. It looks in a folder and lists the filenames in it. For each file in the folder it creates a checklistbox item, listbox item and two checkboxes. This is working great and as intended:

```
 private void getAllFiles(string type)
    {
        try
        {
            string listPath = "not_defined"; 
            if (type == "internal_mod")
            {
                int first_line = 76;
                int next_line = 0;
                int i = 0;
                CheckBox[] chkMod = new CheckBox[100];
                CheckBox[] chkTool = new CheckBox[100];
                listPath = this.internalModsPath.Text;
                string[] filesToList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(listPath);
                foreach (string file in filesToList)
                {     
                    if (!internalModsChkList.Items.Contains(file))
                    {
                        internalModsChkList.Items.Add(file, false);
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                        internalModNameList.Items.Add(fileName);

                        //-----------------
                        // Draw Checkboxes
                        //-----------------
                        chkMod[i] = new CheckBox();                                                 chkTool[i] = new CheckBox();
                        chkMod[i].Name = "modChk" + i.ToString();                                   chkTool[i].Name = "modChk" + i.ToString();
                        //chkMod[i].TabIndex = i;                                                   //chkTool[i].TabIndex = i;
                        chkMod[i].Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);                  chkTool[i].Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);
                        chkMod[i].Checked = true;                                                   chkTool[i].Checked = false;
                        chkMod[i].AutoCheck = true;                                                 chkTool[i].AutoCheck = true;
                        chkMod[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(549, first_line + next_line, 15, 15);      chkTool[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(606, first_line + next_line, 15, 15);

                        groupBox7.Controls.Add(chkMod[i]);                                          groupBox7.Controls.Add(chkTool[i]);
                        //-----------------

                        next_line += 15;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now my problem is that I also want the user to be able to delete all these thing again based on the checklistbox' checked items.. I have no problems deleting the items in the checklistbox or the items in the listbox, but I want to remove the two checkboxes I create too ..

This is what I got to remove the items in the checklistbox, and the listbox

```
private void internalModListDel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = internalModsChkList.Items.Count;
        for (int index = count; index > 0; index--)
        {
            if (internalModsChkList.CheckedItems.Contains(internalModsChkList.Items[index - 1]))
            {
                internalModsChkList.Items.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                internalModNameList.Items.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                groupBox7.Controls.Remove(modChk[index - 1]);
            }

        }


    }
```

As you can see I have also tried to write something to remove the checkbox but it doesn't work and I have no idea how to make it work

Can you assist ?

Comment: In the part of your code dealing with the CheckBoxes deletions (`groupBox7.Controls.Remove(modChk[index - 1]);`), you refer to an array (`modChk`) which is not being populated anywhere. You have either to use `chkMod` (after declaring it globally) or "remove by name": `groupBox7.Controls.RemoveByKey("modChk" + (index - 1).ToString());` (update the indexing part to meet your requirements).

Comment: This actually works, but i have a problem that i didnt think about. Take a look at this pic to see how it looks [link](http://peecee.dk/uploads/102013/screenshot.jpg) The problem is that when i delete a line the checklistbox and listbox automaticly moves all items top most, which the checkboxes do not .. Maybe i should think of a whole other way of doing this instead.

Comment: The posted code cannot work, but if it works with you (because of having further variables) excellent. Regarding what you are saying now, note that when you have a checkbox for a deletion action, the given checkbox is expected to be automatically deleted together with the item. In any case, remember how questions should be asked in SO. You were asking why your code does not delete checkboxes and I gave you some hints there (and you have an answer with another suggestion). If you want to get some advise regarding how to face certain problem, post a new, clear-enough question.

Comment: What i meant was that your suggestion made it work so thanks ! But then as i mentioned above i faced a problem i had not thought about. So i think im gonna try another approuch to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UserControls.
Use the ListBox controller to show those UserControls, 
The user control can be built with those checkboxes, and the labels you want .

Another suggestion is to bind this list to an ObservableCollection which will contain the UserContorols you have created.

This way, it will be much more simlpe to add/remove/change the items inside.